# How to avoid overwriting/loss of data validations in excel during copy paste?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macros enabled workbook and there are certain data validations like input messages etc., defined and used in the VBA code for the macros to function properly. But when users are trying to copy paste the data from other sources these validations are lost and in turn the macros when run are resulting in runtime errors.

I have tried to explore multiple sites and could see only options like restricting copy paste or throwing a warning message. But for my business case users work with huge data sets and restricting copy paste is not the user friendly way.

Hence any possible solutions would be of great help! ~ Thanks, JM

Comment: Have a look at [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Right now there is little to go by.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean datatype to track "Application.CutCopyMode" in the Workbook.Activate event.

```
Private blCCP As Boolean 'Boolean CutCopyPaste

Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    If Application.CutCopyMode Then
        blCCP = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If blCCP = True Then
        '
        'Enter code to apply data validation
        '
        blCCP = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This will detect if `CutCopyMode` is switched on when your workbook is activated.
After user pastes somewhere in the workbook, `Workbook_SheetCalculate` event is triggered.
In that event, put the VBA code to apply all your data validation.

I hope this helps you out.

Edit: Make sure you put this code in `ThisWorkbook` under **Microsoft Excel Objects** in Project Window.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the information Hrishikesh, I will give a try.

Comment: I was also able to find an alternative approach "Paste Special" --> Which enables to copy paste only the values without impacting the formulas or data validations. Please refer to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/paste-special-when-copying-from-excel-6eafd4c6-388c-4938-a7a9-a76afcd5f5c3 for more information.